# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: animation, armature, export

I'm using a plugin to export my model to a special format, however, upon exporting, I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'`.

Here is the exact error message and `.blend` file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY64z.jpg
https://files.fm/u/576pcnmc

I posted this as an issue on the GitHub page, and received the following explanation:

> ...it seems you have an object in your scene that isn't linked to the armature that controls it, so when trying to find the armature to export it's bones the "explorer is giving a null pointer error.

Any idea of how to apply this solution to my `.blend` file? Thanks!

(I've tried setting parents to the armatures, but that doesn't seem to work)

Comment: It expects the mesh to be a child of the armature, possibly also expects only the mesh object to be selected when you export.

Comment: It might be related to this bug: https://developer.blender.org/T53065